# Drude model: A concerning approach to $\tau$ hurts Ohm's Law

Tags: electricity, conductors

[image: Crude Drude model analysis]

Here's the question. Between two points, $a$ and $b$, if an object is accelerated between them, it will cross the distance between them in time $t=\sqrt{2\frac{d}{a}}$. So, if the acceleration is increased, the time decreases with the square root of $a$.

If we take the average $t$ for sinusoidally distributed $d$ values, our $\tau$ should be $\tau = \frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}$. Therefore, increasing the $E$ field should decrease the value of $\tau$ by the square root of the increase. Therefore, the current density equation $j=nq^2\frac{\tau}{m}E$ should be scaling up $j$ by the square root of $E$ since we substitute $\tau=\sqrt{\frac{d}{E}}$. This defeats [Ohm's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm's_law). I don't want it to though because its seemingly wrong, but I don't know why.

Comment: Some kind of schematic would be nice. This setup is hard to imagine.

Comment: I have TeXified your post, but I must say that it is still hard to parse for me, mainly due to unexplained notation/context: Apart from the title, there is no indication that we are talking about [the Drude model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model) of conduction. Are you using the notation from that article?

Comment: Thanks a lot @ACuriousMind. Yes the distance d between points a and b is modeled after the distance between two positive ions in the metal lattice.

Comment: I may attempt a picture. Be advised I'm no art major

Comment: I've seen worse pictures ;) Now, I don't really know the Drude model, but I don't think the sinusoidal distribution of $d$ you use is obvious (sorry if it is).

Comment: Whoah easy there. I'm as confused as anyone in things haha. Usually when things are randomly distributed, they are less concentrated on the outside extremes than on the inside. Sinusoidal averages are what are used for 'average' resistance which is rms resistance. I'm talking about ac circuits, here you go:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square the entry on sine waves is what I meant. Sorry if this doesn't apply, but any average seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems right, but due to your unconventional (most of the time, like below, they do it with velocity, not distance) derivation of the electron kinematics (which are, I should point out, just an approximation), I think the source of your problem is that you still have $d$ in your final Ohm's law. If you replaced that by the more usual terms ($\tau$ and $E$), you'll probably get the right relation.

Here is the quick little derivation from p7 of Ashcroft and Mermin:

Common definition of current: $j = nqv_{avg}$

$t$ is time since electron's last collision. In this time it has force $qE$ acting on it, so accelerates at $a=qE/m$, so in time $t$ will gain velocity $v=at=qEt/m$. Plugging this into the above definition for current, $j=nqv=nq^2tE/m$.

(an important little detail they mention is that we assume the electron left its last collision with a random velocity $v_0$, but those all average out among all the electrons. The velocity from $E$ doesn't, though.)

Comment: True. My final equation has a d and an a, but I'm precisely saying that t, the time between collisions, should decrease with an increasing electric field. I'm deriving this (no doubt slightly incorrectly)

Comment: It seems that the above equation doesn't allow t to change based on how hard the electrons are being pushed

Comment: @AndresSalas, I think you've stated the Drude model: $\tau$ is independent of $E$. Again, it's an approximation, but I think it works because (in a semiclassical model) the average electron speed is very high and can be estimated from $.5mv^2=1.5k_BT$ and the distance between atoms is (mostly) fixed, so you have $l=v_0 \tau$.

Comment: So you're saying that tau is independent of E? How can this be? If I push air through a tube with a lattice of internal sticks, the average time between air and stick collisions is certainly dependent on the hardness of the push, otherwise in the limit of zero pushing there wouldn't be less collisions than at the time when some pushing occurs. But of course, blowing air causes more collisions.

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch your edit, I see I've opened up a whole can of worms. The actual electron speed is very high, so the difference between normal electrons and current is slight. It's hard to say that there were collisions beforehand though for the simple reason that the electrons were in the ground state. How can you impart momentum in the ground state? You can't. Thanks for the added complexity though.

Comment: @AndresSalas, in reality it isn't true, but it's pretty close: like I said, the average electron speed is very high (about $c/100$), whereas the drift velocity (the one that $E$ gives rise to) is very slow. Take a look at their calculation here, where they compare the two: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity Therefore, the effect of $E$ changing the velocity (and thus $\tau$) is nearly nothing.

Comment: Hey! The V in PV=nkBT is not velocity! It's volume isn't it?

Comment: Uhh, yes. But in this case I'm referencing the Equipartition Theorem.

Comment: Ohh right. They seemed so similar I was compelled to comment. I have a question though. Can we truly assume that the electrons were colliding with the positive ions if the electrons were in their lowest available energy state? How can they impart energy?

Answer (score 4):

The electric field (or whatever force) has only a very small effect on the time between collisions.  The reason is that electrons are very light, and their thermal velocity exceeds any change in the velocity due to the applied fields.
One thus treats the scattering time (tau) as a constant.
The applied electric field then causes a drift velocity, tau*acceleration.
Oh, it's assumed that every collision resets the electron velocity randomly... it doesn't remember it's previous velocity.

Comment: The previous section helped me clear up this important concept where drift velocity =slight compared to electron velocity. Thank you, it's very interesting

Comment: So how does current affect temperature so pronouncedly if the time between collisions is always on average~the same?